# Create a UIBezierPath (or CGPath) with a Quarter-Circle Arc that's the 'Opposite' of a Rounded Corner

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiview, calayer, uibezierpath

I've been using the following code to create **views with rounded corners**:

```
- (void)setMaskTo:(UIView*)view byRoundingCorners:(UIRectCorner)corners
{
    UIBezierPath* rounded = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:view.bounds
                                                  byRoundingCorners:corners
                                                        cornerRadii:CGSizeMake(_cornerRadius, _cornerRadius)];
    CAShapeLayer* shape = [[CAShapeLayer alloc] init];
    [shape setPath:rounded.CGPath];
    view.layer.mask = shape;
}
```

So I've been calling it with something like:

```
[self setMaskTo:someView byRoundingCorners:UIRectCornerAllCorners];
```

Or:

```
[self setMaskTo:someOtherView byRoundingCorners:UIRectCornerBottomRight];
```

I now want to create some views corresponding to one of the bits on **the outside of a single rounded corner**...

A good approach (think I) is to create the appropriate *path* so that I can create a `CAShapeLayer` and then use that as the *mask* for the view (similar to above).

I'm not sure what the best approach is, which methods etc., when using the `UIBezierPath` class (or `CGPath`).

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `UIView`s and a mask layer, to get the *shapes* that I wanted, I just needed to play around creating *paths* with an *arc*...

I'm aware that the methods for working with a `CGPath` can be used, but I've worked with what is available with [UIBezierPath](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIBezierPath_class/Reference/Reference.html).

I've used the following methods to create the paths that I need:

```
- (UIBezierPath*)oppositeArcOfPathForBottomRightCorner
{
    float width = _cornerRadius;
    UIBezierPath* path = [UIBezierPath new];
    [path moveToPoint:CGPointMake(0, width)];
    [path addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(width, width)];
    [path addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(width, 0)];
    [path addArcWithCenter:CGPointMake(0, 0) radius:width startAngle:0 endAngle:(M_PI / 2.0f) clockwise:YES];
    [path closePath];
    return path;
}

- (UIBezierPath*)oppositeArcOfPathForTopLeftCorner
{
    float width = _cornerRadius;
    UIBezierPath* path = [UIBezierPath new];
    [path moveToPoint:CGPointMake(0, width)];
    [path addArcWithCenter:CGPointMake(width, width) radius:width startAngle:M_PI endAngle:(M_PI * 1.5f) clockwise:YES];
    [path addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(0, 0)];
    [path closePath];
    return path;
}
```

And then something like this to use as a mask with a `UIView`:

```
- (void)setMaskTo:(UIView*)view fromPath:(UIBezierPath*)path
{
    CAShapeLayer* shape = [[CAShapeLayer alloc] init];
    [shape setPath:path.CGPath];
    view.layer.mask = shape;
}
```